# Normalizing votes based on source's rank

Tags: voting-theory

If article a from source A has 100 votes, and article b from source B has 10 votes, without simply saying that article a is better because it was voted more, how can I normalize the weight of these votes based on source popularity? Seen in that light, if source A is incredibly popular, 100 votes is actually not so much. If B is incredibly unpopular, 10 votes might be a game changer.

Is there any way to describe this mathematically?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to ask what fraction of the votes on source A went to article a and compare that to the fraction of the votes on source B went to article b.  So if source A gathers a million votes for all the articles, and article a only got 100 or $0.01\%$ of them while source B got 100 votes and article b got 10 or $10\%$ of them, you could rate b higher.  Maybe there are more articles on source A, so you should look at the fair share of votes for each article.  There are many possibilities.  Maybe the voters on source A don't give out votes as easily as those on B....

Comment: So essentially the standard score of article a (given other articles from source A) and the standard score of article b (given other articles from source B), correct? Suppose I have the rank of A and B, how could I let those play into the equation?

Comment: What are you measuring for the ranks of A and B?  You have number of users, number of votes, number of articles, and maybe other data.  I was suggesting weighting by some measures of the "size" of A and B, but that is not a ranking.